# IOS UITextView category set font

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview, uifont

I created a category class which standardize the feel and look of UITextView.
I manage to add border with the code below but not sure how to set font name, font color.

```
#import "UITextView+Form.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UITextView (Form)

-(void)standardize{
    CALayer *thisLayer = self.layer;
    thisLayer.borderWidth=3.0;
    thisLayer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

}
@end
```

Comment: What @H2CO3 means is, "please don't label questions as Xcode unless it's about the IDE specifically". If it's about iOS development, label as "iOS", "Objective-C", or something else similar as such ;-)

Comment: I would recommend adding a class method to `UITextView` that creates the 'standard' `UITextView` for your application, instead of having an instance method. It would be something like `+ (UITextView *)standardTextView` and would initialize and set the default properties of the text view, and return it. This 'factory' class method is the typical approach, as seen in e.g. `[UIColor redColor]`. This is more stylistic than functional, though.

Comment: I agree with @MaxGabriel, this would be more convenient as a class method instead of an instance method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method should work for you:

```
-(void)standardize{
    CALayer *thisLayer = self.layer;
    thisLayer.borderWidth=3.0;
    thisLayer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    // Set whatever point size you want
    self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0f];    

    // Set whatever color you want
    self.textColor = [UIColor black];
}
```

These should help too.

UIFont class reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html

UIColor class reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to your `standardize` method:

```
self.textColor = [UIColor ...]; // whatever color you want
self.font = [UIFont ...]; // whatever font you want
```